# Issue with files in java

Tags: java

I made a class that stores and retrieve data from a file, but when i ran the code i got errors such as

```
Error retrieving infojava.io.FileNotFoundException: computer-db.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: computer-db.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at testing.Driver.retrieve(Driver.java:63)
at testing.Driver.main(Driver.java:19)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at testing.Driver.retrieve(Driver.java:89)
at testing.Driver.main(Driver.java:19)
```

Whenever i run it this would show up in the console output. I also realize that the file isn't being created when i run the program

here is the driver file i wrote to store and read from a file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Computer c1=new Computer();
        c1.display();   

        Computer p=new Computer();
        try {
            p=retrieve();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        p.display();

    }

    public static void store(Computer c) throws IOException {
        FileWriter pc=new FileWriter("computer-db.txt");
        try {
            pc.write(c.getOwnername()+"\t");
            pc.write(c.getModel()+"\t");
            pc.write(c.getColor()+"\t");
            pc.write(c.getCentralprocessingunit().getClockspeed()+"\t");
            pc.write(c.getCentralprocessingunit().getManufacturer()+"\t");
            pc.write(c.getCentralprocessingunit().getNumcores()+"\n");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("error writing to the file "+ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(pc != null) {
                    pc.close();
                }
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error with file "+ex);
            }
        }           
    }

    public static Computer retrieve()throws Exception {
        Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner rfile= null;
        Computer pc=new Computer();
        try {
            rfile=new Scanner(new File("computer-db.txt"));
            System.out.println("Enter the name to search for: ");
            String srcParam = read.next();
            while(rfile.hasNext()) {
                String ownername=rfile.next();
                String model=rfile.next();
                String color=rfile.next();
                double clockspeed=rfile.nextDouble();
                String manufacturer=rfile.next();
                int numcores=rfile.nextInt();

                if(ownername.equals(srcParam)) {
                    pc = new Computer(ownername,model,color,clockspeed,
                        manufacturer,numcores);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error retrieving info"+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rfile.close();
            read.close();
        }
        return pc;
    }
}
```

does anyone know how to resolve this issue?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The path is obviously wrong.  If you package this app in a JAR or WAR you cannot access it using the file system; you should be using input streams from the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Your code never calls `store()` so how do you expect the file to be created? Also note that using relative paths that way makes your program dependent on the folder you're starting it from.

Comment: You'll also want to use flush and try-with-resources to make the code simpler.

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` is telling you that file doesn't exist. You are trying to open `computer-db.txt` in the current directory. Is the file really there?

Comment: i thought java automatically makes the file. The project is stored in a folder on my desktop

Comment: Java knows nothing about `computer-db.txt`. However, your program has a method `store()` which looks like it was supposed to create exactly this file.

Answer (score 0):

The file computer-db.txt should be located in the same folder that your program's executable jar file is being executed from.  The same applies if you are not using a jar file but are instead executing directly from the class file that has the main method.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are not storing data onto file before retrieving it, Also you haven't handled the FileNotFound exception well, To handle this you can do the following

FileWriter has 5 different constructors, the one used assumes file is already present, as file doesn't exist it's throwing error

so you can modify your code like this :

```
File file = new File("computer-db.txt");
if(!file.exists)
{
  file.createNewFile();
}

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
```

Secondly in the exception handling it's good practice to provide appropriate message instead of just printing stack trace.